# Limit on page display only

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask if there would be a solution to query the MySQL database trough PHP to load only 1 page from a set of results but in the pagination to still display like [1] 2 3 4 5... So when the user clicks the page two like 1 [2] 3 4 5... then to load the second page and so on?

My database is very huge and to load 1000 pages at once would consume a lot of bandwidth and it takes for the process about 50 seconds which is too much.

I need to find a solution to lower the loading time. My actual query looks like :

```
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$query = '
        SELECT *, (MATCH(url) AGAINST('.$qo1.''.$out.''.$qo2.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.015 + MATCH(title) AGAINST ('.$qo1.''.$out.''.$qo2.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.015 + MATCH(description,body) AGAINST('.$qo1.''.$out.''.$qo2.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.040 + MATCH(keywords) AGAINST ('.$qo1.''.$out.''.$qo2.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.030) AS relevance
        FROM table
        WHERE MATCH(url, title, description, body, keywords) AGAINST ('.$qo1.''.$out.''.$qo2.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ORDER BY relevance '.$ord.' LIMIT '.$start.','.$per_page.'';
```

Regards

Comment: How is this different from basic pagination?

Comment: It loads all the pages at once and limit them by 20 results per page, but a user won't be satisfied to wait that long until the load is complete, so my point is to load only 20 results but to check how many results per total and to load the second page only if the user do click it, otherwise not to load all 10.000 results.

Comment: Just take a look at some more examples of pagination. For instance, how does google do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script pointed me out on the right direction into building my pagination to only allow results to be received in by page displayed.

```
<?php 
// Script and tutorial written by Adam Khoury @ developphp.com // Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw 
include_once("mysqli_connection.php"); 
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); 
// Here we have the total row count 
$rows = $row[0]; 
// This is the number of results we want displayed per page 
$page_rows = 10; 
// This tells us the page number of our last page 
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1 
if($last < 1){ $last = 1; } 
// Establish the $pagenum variable 
$pagenum = 1; 
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1 
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){ $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']); }
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our 
$last page if ($pagenum < 1) 
{ $pagenum = 1; } 
else if ($pagenum > $last) 
{ $pagenum = $last; } 
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum 
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
// This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit 
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, datemade FROM testimonials WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages 
$textline1 = "Testimonials (<b>$rows</b>)"; $textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>"; 
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable 
$paginationCtrls = ''; 
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results 
if($last != 1){ 
/* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */ 
if ($pagenum > 1) 
{ $previous = $pagenum - 1; 
$paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; '; 
// Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number 
for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++)
{ if($i > 0)
{ $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; '; 
} 
} 
} 
// Render the target page number, but without it being a link 
$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; '; 
// Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number 
for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++)
{ $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
 if($i >= $pagenum+4){ break; } 
} 
// This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next" 
if ($pagenum != $last) 
{ $next = $pagenum + 1; 
$paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
 } 
 } 
 $list = ''; 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 { $id = $row["id"];
 $firstname = $row["firstname"]; 
 $lastname = $row["lastname"]; 
 $datemade = $row["datemade"]; 
 $datemade = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($datemade)); 
 $list .= '<p><a href="testimonial.php?id='.$id.'">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' Testimonial</a> - Click the link to view this testimonial<br>Written '.$datemade.'</p>';
 } 
 // Close your database connection 
 mysqli_close($db_conx); 
 ?>
```